Battery Unbalancing Situation
I have a question about the battery pack design. The datasheet of the battery is attached to this question.

The battery pack consists of 3 different module and each module contains 8 series and 2 paralel (8S2P) configuration. The information of cells i will use in the battery pack design is like the picture.

As seen in the random screenshot, I short-circuited one of the cells using a wire (imagine a wire with a much lower internal resistance). In this way, I will create an imbalance in the battery pack. In such a scenario, how would the battery pack react (assuming I am not using active or passive balancing methods)? Would an overcurrent situation occur through the other cells and modules? I would like to express my gratitude in advance for your answers.
All cells can be considered fully charged for the calculation.

You say "My goal is to create an imbalance and determine whether these fuses will trip if enough current is drawn from the other cells. " That is a valid question. 1) Submit a new question. 2) Ask that question in the title and the text. 3) Provide an accurate  schematic diagram (not a block diagram) so we can see how the cells are connected.

Your focus on balancing is curious, given that a battery with a shorted cell is a "time bomb". Balancing is the least of your concerns.
You don't say whether that cell is directly across another cell or by itself in series with other cells. So I'll address both cases.

The BMS sees that the cell voltage is too low and shut down the battery. (You DO have a BMS, right? Right?)
The shorted cell will overheat due to its own high current.
If the cell is in parallel with other cells (a cell block), it will overheat due to the high current from the cells in parallel with it.
In either case, the cell may go into thermal runaway.
If the BMS controls a single switch for the entire battery, the strings will remain connected in parallel. The total open circuit voltage (OCV) of the good strings is 3.7 V or so higher than the OCV of the bad string. Therefore, there will be a significant current from the other strings into the string with the shorted cell. (*)
That current will overcharge the rest of the cells in the bad string and the BMS will notice, but there's not a thing that the BMS can do about it because the current is not flowing through the protection switch. (*)

(*) If each string has its own switch, and the BMS shuts off all of them, then this is not a problem.

More to the point, I suspect that you're asking due to a fear that a cell may suddenly short out. If so, allow me to say that your fear is misplaced:

Cells in a battery properly protected by a BMS do not fail as a short circuit (**). They fail as gradually lower capacity and higher resistance. Therefore, you should focus on proper BMS implementation instead of a fear of a short circuit.
Cell do fail as a soft short (10s of ohms, not 0 Ohm) due to manufacturing defects (rare these days). But a soft short circuit results in a thermal runaway long before it results in an excessive current. In that case, the battery is on fire and your question becomes of secondary importance.

(**) Cells in a battery that is not protected do fail as a hard short circuit, due to overcharging of over-discharging.

Thank you for the clear explanation, Sir. Yes, I have a BMS to check the value of the cell. It collects the data from the monitoring system. However, I want to perform a test on the modules without using a BMS. If I create this environment, we will be using a mechanical fuse between each cell (4 mechanical fuses in the bus with 8 series). My concern is whether the mechanical fuse makes sense when we already have a BMS in our design.

Additionally, we want to place a mechanical fuse between the cells. In the event of a hard internal short in the cell, will the mechanical fuse protect the cell and battery pack from resulting in thermal runaway?

"My concern is whether the mechanical fuse makes sense when we already have a BMS in our design. " Given the premise I explained in my answer ("Cells in a battery properly protected by a BMS do not fail as a short circuit"), adding fuses is unnecessary. Witness that Tesla had fuses in their original traction batteries. They don't anymore: they too realized they are not needed. This too is a valid question. 1) Start a new submission and 2) Ask that question in the title.

Yes - if the BMS (Battery Management System) is looking at total voltage it will over-charge the other cells to compensate for the cell that will not fully charge.
If each module has its own BMS, then Module 1 will be the only one affected.
You can isolate the single cell and attempt to "bump" it back to the same charge as the other cells in the pack, but you would have to detach it from the pack and re-connect it to do so, at which point it may be worth while to simply replace the bad cell.
The worse the cell gets, the more over-charged the others will become. Balance charging is really the only way to fix it without a full replacement.
